# Controlling Package Level Javadoc Generation

Tags: java, javadoc

When Javadoc processed a package-info.java file in Java 8, the output placed the Javadoc comments (except for the summary sentence) after the generated class and other summary tables.  Here is a Java 8 example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Sometime between Java 8 and Java 11 this changed, and the Javadoc output in Java 11 now places all Javadoc comments before the generated class and other summary tables.  Here is the same example in Java 11: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

What I'd like, but have been unable to find, is a way to control this behavior in Java 11.  I'd prefer to revert to the Java 8 behavior (in Java 11) or, even better, to be able
to control this behavior such that some package comments appear before and some after the summary tables.

Is there a way to control this Javadoc behavior in Java 11?  At the moment I am constrained to Java 11 and cannot use features from earlier or later versions.

Answer (score 0):

[From Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-C27CE557-E5C6-4688-9FA5-9E9DE886A569)

> ​You can customize the content and format of the javadoc command output
> with doclets. The javadoc command has a default built-in doclet,
> called the Standard Doclet, that generates HTML-formatted API
> documentation. You can write your own doclet to generate HTML, XML,
> MIF, RTF or whatever output format you want.

The [StandardDoclet](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/doclet/StandardDoclet.java) delegates to [HtmlDoclet](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/doclets/formats/html/HtmlDoclet.java). You might be able to get away with subclassing that and overriding `generatePackageFiles`.

IMO probably not worth the effort, but hey.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I had already decided not to pursue the custom doclet approach.  Definitely not worth the effort for my application.  I may need to look at moving some information from the package-info.java file to a separate HTML file, and linking to that from the Javadoc.